# Reloading the content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm creating an extension for a site so that when a user types :) it changes to a graphical emotion. It all works fine when I refresh the page.

The problem is, when a user on the site types a message it's done using ajax, so there is no page load. I need a way to reload the content script, or to change the ASCII emotion to an image without reloading the page.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is your extension targeting one specific site, or all sites?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for keyup events on the textarea or form submits if you only want to change the emotion at the end. [jQuery().on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) should let you do this. For example `$('#textarea').on('keyup', changeEmot)` or `$('#form').on('submit', changeEmot)`. You may have to play around with the selectors and the events you get the gist.